# Exporting the filepath of all music files to a text file

Tags: terminal, music, path

I'd love to know the syntax within Terminal to export the filename and path of all my music of various types (I have legacy Windows `.wma` files too). I'd presumably export those file to a `.txt` or `.xls` file and sort by path.

My ultimate problem is my music is in many different folders (somewhere between 3 and 10 main places) and contain many duplicates - like 40GB of duplicates. I keep wasting time with software that doesn't work, but if I know where all the music is located (and exactly how big the files are), I can know how to better attack the problem - i.e., maybe I'll just drag them to a Windows machine (via a HD or Dropbox) where their folder merge options work better.

Comment: You had two questions in here. This site works better when there is only one question per question. That way, it's easier for other people to find solutions if they have the same problem. I've edited out your second question, but feel free to ask it separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might just use `find`:

```
find ~/Music > ~/music.txt
```

Or add for example `-iname \*.mp3` to only include files that end with `.mp3`:

```
find ~/Music -iname \*.m4a -o -iname \*.mp3 -o -iname \*.flac -o -iname \*.wma > ~/music.txt
```

If the problem is that your music is scattered throughout your directories and not contained within your `~/Music` folder - and if you want to export the paths to a file - then you would want to do this:

```
find ~/ -iname \*.m4a -o -iname \*.mp3 -o -iname \*.flac -o -iname \*.wma > ~/Desktop/music.txt
```